# Knockout.js event context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I started reimplementing some js code with knockout.js.
I have a singleton with some functions in it:

```
Dps = {
    someFunction: function() {
        this.anotherFunction();
    },
    anotherFunction: function() {
        console.log('tehee');
    }
}
```

Now there are also some bindings which calls functions of this singleton:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: { change: Dps.someFunction }" />
```

The annoying thing is, that the context in the called function is the event, so I can't call `this.anotherFunction()`

Is there a nice way to get rid of this?

PS: I'm aware that I could do something like Dps.someFunction() instead, but this is not nice in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-bind="event: { change: Dps.someFunction.bind(Dps) }"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Doesn't have that broad browser support though. Most notably not supported in IE8.

Comment: @MartinHansen Right, that's why I linked the article so you could use the code there that works in IE6+. If you're using jQuery you can use jQuery's equivalent: `$.proxy( Dps.someFunction, Dps )`

Comment: Ah ok, just scrolled right to browser compability table at bottom :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm using jQuery and that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions behaves as "static"

So either you have to do Dps.anotherFunction but you don't want that, but I don't see why tbh.

You can also call **ko.applyBindings(Dps)** and then your code would work fine. However I guess that's not what you're looking for either. Probably you have another viewmodel all together, no?

Another solution is to make Dps into a function which you instantiate

On jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PrbqZ/

```
<input type="text" data-bind="event: { change: myDps.someFunction }" />

var Dps = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.someFunction = function() {
        self.anotherFunction();
    };

    this.anotherFunction = function() {
        console.log('tehee');
    };
}

var myDps = new Dps();

//normally use dom ready, just simulating here
setTimeout(function(){
    ko.applyBindings();
}, 500)
```